# Adding a resource based policy vs IAM policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-secrets-manager

I want to have a `lambda` accessing secret manager.

For reasons beyond the scope of this question, I want to go with a resource based policy.

So I am considering allowing principal `lambda-my-lambda` in the specific SM secret.

Will I **also** need to add a specific IAM policy to the lambda's executor role?

Or will just the resource based policy allow `lambda-my-lambda` to access the secrets' manager secret?

Comment: "resource based policy"  will be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either is sufficient on its own.

[Identity-based policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/auth-and-access_iam-policies.html) = "Entry Pass"

- Permissions policy is attached to your Lambda Role

[Resource-based policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/auth-and-access_resource-policies.html) = "Guest List"

- Permissions policy is attached to the Secret
- `"Principal": <Lambda Role ARN>`

Comment: Excellent analogy